# Best way to get data from non-admins internal to an organization in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, web

Here's the scenario:

I want to display a music playlist for each DJ at a radio station on my Wordpress site, but I don't want to have to enter that data in (Each song, artist, album, etc), in a specific custom post type or something like that.

I want each DJ to have access to a form where they can enter the playlist data in, and I can use that data. I was thinking of making a little webpage form that they can access, and then I query the database to get all that stuff, but I imagine that maybe there is an easier way using Wordpress.

The thing is, I don't want to give each DJ admin access to make posts with those custom fields filled in, so I'm not sure if there's a way to do that.
Maybe a page on the website that is password protected to fill out the form, and then I can use that data in a different page on the site? (Password protected so I'm only receiving data from actual DJs, not random people or bots.)

Sorry if this is an ignorant question, or if I'm unclear.
I searched a little bit, and couldn't find much.

Thanks in advance for ideas and insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decide your method for doing this and try it out, when you run into a problem then you post here. It sounds like you know what you need. You're looking for a password protected form (which will check against a database) and pages based on a query to the database. This can be done in PHP or you might be able to find a Wordpress plugin to help you out.

Maybe start by making the PHP form. Then you could add the password protection. After you have that working you could make the PHP page that would query the information submitted. Take it one step at a time. It'll be much easier for people to help you if you're troubleshooting a specific issue rather than trying to figure out the logistics of how the whole system will work.

Comment: I got you. I've come up with a game plan of creating a password protected page and grabbing the info with php after the form on the page is filled out.

Comment: I thought maybe this would be a place to help brainstorm ideas as well, but i understand the idea of having something more specific to debug